# IOS 7 UIButton only responding when tapping on it's text label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, ios7

I have a large UIButton which I have subclassed and set background colour  during tap.

```
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(releasedInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(releasedOutside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

However it seems that it only responds when I am pressing at the area with text on the button. I want it to respond also when I tap on the coloured background. How to do this?

Comment: what is in `self`? is it `UIlabel` object or `UIButton` object

Comment: How are you laying out your button?  Is it possible that autolayout is shrinking your button to be the size of its title?

Comment: self is the subclassed UIButton, I lay it out in the storyboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The button is not responding to taps inside it (I have a border around it so I know it's bounds) because I have set the background to transparent before it is tapped.

I managed to do a workaround by setting:

[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.01]];

Very weird why it is like this...

Comment: Have you tried modifying the type of the UIButton? (custom .. etc)

Comment: This also helps for widgets with transparant buttons!! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this. It seems that iOS doesn't register a tap if your button and your UIView both have transparent backgrounds. I guess this is because you are tapping on an "undrawn" part of the screen, so it means that you can only tap on the colored button label. I got around this by setting a black background on my main UIView.